# It it possible to call async method inside constructor?

Tags: dart

I need to call second method only when first one is complete. Both of them are async. I wrote next code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  TenderApiData _tenderApiData;
  MyApp(this._tenderApiData)
  {
    _tenderApiData.getApiKey().then(
      _tenderApiData.getRegionsList()
    );
  }
}
```

But I am getting error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => FutureOr' of 'f'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then syntax of the [then](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Future/then.html) method is wrong in your case, it expects a function that returns a `FutureOr<R>` not a Future itself.

You code should be

```
    _tenderApiData.getApiKey().then((_) =>
      _tenderApiData.getRegionsList()
    );
```

You can replace `_` if intend to use the `Future`'s returned value

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  TenderApiData _tenderApiData;
  MyApp(this._tenderApiData) {
     _tenderApiData.getApiKey().then(( _) {
       _tenderApiData.getRegionsList()
      });
  }
}
```